# PowerShell - Catching Error not exporting to Out-File

Tags: powershell, error-handling, catch-block

I have a script to list permissions on a remote machine.  The try{} works perfectly without errors, which is fine.  The catch{} however does not.  The script block is below:

```
Try{
    $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $CompName -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
    $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
    $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $CompName -Filter $query
    $list | %{$_.PartComponent} | % {$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"","\")}-ErrorAction Stop| Out-File C:\AdminList\$CompName\AdminListResults\$CompName.txt
    Write-Host "Sequence Completed. Logs have been exported to $CompName folder." -ForegroundColor Cyan
}

catch{
    $Error[0]| Out-File C:\AdminList\$CompName\ErrorLogs\$CompName.txt
    Write-Host "Errors Found. See ErrorLogs for details" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

What I was hoping to have it do was that if the try{} failed, it catches the error displayed, hides it from the console and exports it to a location specified but this is the part not working.  What is currently happening is that the try{} runs, the error is displayed in the console and the write-host from the try{} appears, NOT the catch{} write host.

Any advice would be great. I browsed Stack for answers but couldn't find any. My last question was closed because it was too broad so I hope this has more detail for better understanding.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into a non-terminating error. These kinds of errors do not throw an exception but you can do it manually. To verify, append -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to both of your Get-WmiObject calls.  If you don't get an error, that is the case. In order to capture those still, you can use the -ErrorVariable parameter and then put that into the file.

```
try
{
    Get-WmiObject -Class whatever -ErrorVariable err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($err)
    {
        throw $err  
    }
}
catch
{
    ## whatever you want to do here
}
```

Comment: Edited code is below:

`Try{
$group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $CompName -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'" -ErrorVariable $Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($Red)
{
    throw $Red
}
$query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
$list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $CompName -Filter $query -ErrorVariable $Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($Red)
{
    throw $Red
}`

The error is not showing now, which is good but the Catch from the original code is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch my last response. Made some changes on my end and what @adam bertman posted worked perfect!! Thank You!

Comment: Great news! Glad I could help.